# how to change the value of one column for only a selection of records in R

Tags: r

Is there a straightforward way to change the values in column X to NA, based on the value of column Y?

I've got a large dataframe with data for multiple radars. I want to change the column X values (Density) to NA only for radarID "CLX" (column Y).

It Excel this would be a simple select all rows with radarID = "CLX", and replace all Density values with NA.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is as follows. If `df` is your data frame with two columsn `x` and `y` and you want to change `x` based on `y` such that when `y` is less than `10`, `x` should become `NA`:

```
df[df$y < 10, 'x'] <- NA
```

You could also check out `?transform` and `?within`

Answer (score 1):

In R also it is too simple, specially if you give us a reproducible example.

Here I create one :

```
dat <- data.frame( radarID = sample(c("CLX","OTHER"),10,rep=TRUE),
            X = rnorm(10))
```

Then using `transform` and `ifelse`, you can do something like this :

```
transform(dat,X=ifelse(radarID=='CLX',NA,X))

  radarID           X
1    OTHER -1.03632461
2    OTHER  0.07634564
3    OTHER -0.33788092
4      CLX          NA
5      CLX          NA
6      CLX          NA
7    OTHER  1.37040083
8    OTHER  0.50905176
9      CLX          NA
10   OTHER -0.16086215
```

Of course this will work in a copy of your data. You need to assign it assign to dat if you want to have the change.

```
dat <- transform(dat,X=ifelse(radarID=='CLX',NA,X))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = data.frame(Density = 1:4, radarID = c("blah", "boo", "CLX", "bam"))
df$Density[df$radarID == "CLX"] = NA
```